# Free upper limit of axes (not bottom) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a sample dataframe:

```
d2 <- structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1 - JL", 
                                                                                                        "11 - KT", "2 - SSD", "3 - USSD", "4 - MES"), class = "factor"), 
                     x = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
                           3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L), y = c(15L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 
                                                              9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 20L, 18L, 22L, 
                                                              16L)), .Names = c("site", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                       -20L))
```

I wish to make graphs using ggplot2:

```
g <- ggplot (df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~site, ncol=2, scales='free_y')

g
```

However I only want to 'free' the upper limit for the graph, not the borrom (set at 0).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
g + expand_limits(y = 0)
```

This will ensure y-axis of all panels start from `y = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
g <- ggplot (d2, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() + expand_limits(y = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~site, ncol=2, scales='free_y')

g
```

Addition of `expand_limits(y = 0)` says that **y axis** should start from **0**.